# Socket message header building

Tags: c#, c++, xml, sockets

I'm working on a protocol which will transfer block of xml data via tcp socket. Now say I need to read all the bytes from a xml file and build a memory buffer. Then before sending the actual data bytes I need to send one header to other peer end. Say my protocol using below header type.

MessageID=100,Size=232,CRC=190

```
string strHeader = "100,232,190"
```

Now I would like to know how can I make this header length fixed (fixed header length is required for other peer to identify it as a header) for any amount of xml data. Currently say I'm having a xml file sized 283637bytes, so the message header will look like.

```
string strHeader = "100,283637,190"
```

How can I make it generic for any size of data? The code is being written both in c++ and c#.

Comment: Make each number a fixed size, with leading zeroes, then the whole header becomes fixed size. The length field will be worst, but unless you will send messages larger than a 9 gigs then ten digits will be enough.

Comment: Yes that was my first thought. But I'm thinking about a Hexadecimal approach.

Comment: The actual format of the data doesn't really matter. Using hexadecimal will make the header smaller (fewer digits) but the principle is still the same: Fixed size number with leading zeroes.

Comment: Leading with 0. Means I will have to treat all the size and crc as string variable.

Comment: Not really. The header itself is a string, but the receiver can easily split it into the three containing parts, and then convert each to integers. Both C# and C++ have standard functions for the conversion, which conveniently ignores leading zeroes.

Comment: hmm.. if I cannot find any other solution willd defenitely go by this way.. currently I'm testing my code with fixed length file size..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74205/discussion-between-plearner-and-joachim-pileborg).

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do it.

**Fixed Length**

You can pad the numbers numbers with leading zeroes so you know exactly what length of the text you need to work with. `000100,000232,000190`

**Use Bytes instead of strings**

If you are using integers, you can read the bytes as integers instead of manipulating the string. Look into the [BinaryReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. If needing to do this on the C++ side, the concept is still the same. I am sure there many ways to convert 4 bytes into an int.

**Specify the length at the beginning**

Usually when working with dynamic length strings. There is an indicator of how many bytes need to be read in order to get the entire string. You could specify the first 4 bytes of your message as the length of your string and then read up to that point.

Comment: Actually my sender app is being written in c++. So can't use BinaryReader class straight away. I want to go with format like. 0x85 0x37 0x3F 0x4A. Any way to achieve that? Sender app is c++. Receiver and parser is c#.

Comment: @PLearner The concept is still the same. I am sure there are many ways to convert `byte[4]` into an `int`.

Comment: @PLearner just saw your edit. Those are still bytes. You could choose to write and read it out in that format after you get the bytes out of the stream, but you'll still be sending 4 bytes of `133, 55, 63, 74` down the wire.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for you is to implement this as a struct like

```
struct typedef _msg_hdr {
     int messageID;
     int size;
     int crc;
}msg_hdr;
```

This will always have 12 bytes length. Now when sending your message, first send header to the receiver. The receiver should receive it in the same structure. This is the best and easiest way

Comment: sending a struct over tcp/ip will be a bit tricky and i dont wanna change my parsing logic at the server side. so no way.

Comment: Dude its practised approach, and trust me its not tricky. you are just sending 12 bytes and receiving 12 bytes like this send(socket_fd, &msg_hdr, sizeof(msg_hdr), 0) and you will receive like recv(socket_fd, &msg_hdr, sizeof(msg_hdr), 0). When you have received just call msg_hdr.size and you will get the value

Comment: My receiving part is in c# and there I'm reading data in bytes[]. So if I need to change the header message to struct then header and data parsing has to be two different method.

Comment: Oh come on. You will receive just 12 bytes. First four bytes are first variable. Next 4 bytes is the size variable and last 4 will be crc. You dont even need structure to translate tjis

Comment: I'm going to give it a try today. Will ping if I struck somewhere. Thanks for your suggestion.